# cookies needed in python requests

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

With a user and pass that is correctly identified on a PC-browser, I tried to access the same url using python requests on the server(localhost)

> r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:1234', auth=('user', 'pass'))

this would return me with 401 Unauth. So I had another try by getting the cookie from my browser (copy and paste the cookie from browser and set a dict and use it in python request module)

> r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:1234', cookies=mycookies),

this would return me 200 OK

However the above script will be shipped, so I do not want to store my cookie hardcoded in the code, also I do not know where the localhost app will be deployed (so mycookies will not be relevant if it is deployed in another server)

I tried to obtain the cookie with the following session:

> session = requests.Session()
>
> session.auth = ('MyUSER', 'MyPASS')
>
> auth = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:1234')
>
> Response [401]

and I got 401

As I know the user and password ( I know this is a really bad practice, but as this is a localhost testing app we can ship this user and password), how can I GET the URL above without using the cookie? Why does the requests.get with auth is rejecting me if not using the cookie?

Additional info:
I tried using Google chrome incognito, and try to use the above auth on the website, and it authenticates me just fine. Why for requests module I need a cookie?

Comment: did you try the auth method with the Session?

Comment: Yes I did . I was using the auth in session as well. Copy paste error in the post, will update the snippet

Comment: Is this some kind of special login? Like a microsoft single sign on type thing?

Comment: @SuperStew I am not familiar with Microsoft single sign on. However i am authenticated on Zope Based Authenticator ( https://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/Security.html )

Comment: I also used Postman + HTTPBasicAuth (but  cookie is there) and it works fine .

Comment: Not familiar with Zope, but to login to an intranet site at work i had to use `requests_ntlm`. worth looking into i think